# Add 1 hour in Current timestamp in KSH

Tags: unix, ksh

How to add 1 hour in unix timestamp

`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`

I need to add 1 hour in above format

Answer (score 0):

A literal answer to your question is to use

```
date --date="next hour" +%Y%m%d_%H%M
```

but I'm guessing that you actually want to display the time in another timezone. To display in UTC:

```
date --utc +%Y%m%d_%H%M
```

and in another timezone, e.g.

```
TZ="Europe/Stockholm" date +%Y%m%d_%H%M
```

assuming of course that system clock is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

De GNU date makes live easy. Without GNU date you can manipulate your timezone:

```
echo "$(TZ=GMT+1 date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)"
```

Be careful with Daylight Saving Time.

You can remember this trick when you to get the date (without time) of yesterday. Just adding 24 hours to the timezone can give problems during the Daylight Saving Time. You can use a trick to find yesterday:

You are sure that yesterday is 20 or 30 hours ago. Which one? Well, the most recent one that is not today.

```
echo "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" |
   grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

Above command is for ksh. When you use bash, you want `echo -e`.
Or use printf:

```
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)" "$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" |
   grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```